# Perl6 search then replace with output of subroutine

Tags: regex, replace, evaluation, raku, string-substitution

I've combed the docs but I can't seem to find how to do this in perl6.

In perl5 I would have done (just an example):

```
sub func { ... }

$str =~ s/needle/func($1)/e;
```

i.e. to replace 'needle' with the output of a call to 'func'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok so we'll start by making a function that just returns our input repeated 5 times

```
sub func($a) { $a x 5 };
```

Make our string

```
my $s = "Here is a needle";
```

And here's the replace

```
$s ~~ s/"needle"/{func($/)}/;
```

Couple of things to notice. As we just want to match a string we quote it. And our output is effectively a double quoted string so to run a function in it we use `{}`. No need for the `e` modifier as all strings allow for that kind of escaping.

[The docs on substitution](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/s$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS) mention that the Match object is put in `$/` so we pass that to our function. In this case the Match object when cast to a String just returns the matched string. And we get as our final result.

```
Here is a needleneedleneedleneedleneedle
```

Comment: "needle" can of course be an actual regex and it works fine with that too.

Comment: Hi Scimon. Nice quick clean answer. `"needle"` could also be `needle`, without the quotes. Presumably you chose/prefer to quote it for clarity?

Answer (score 15):

There is no `e` modifier in Perl 6; instead, the right hand part is treated like a double-quoted string. The most direct way to call a function is therefore to stick an `&` before the function name and use function call interpolation:

```
# An example function
sub func($value) {
    $value.uc
}

# Substitute calling it.
my $str = "I sew with a needle.";
$str ~~ s/(needle)/&func($0)/;
say $str;
```

Which results in "I sew with a NEEDLE.". Note also that captures are numbered from 0 in Perl 6, not 1. If you just want the whole captured string, pass `$/` instead.